# please give me the solution of this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on this link, nothing happens.  What is the problem?

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".link").click(function () {
    var status = $(".link input[name=status]").val();

    if (status == "delete") {
      alert("it works.");
    }
  });

});
```

This is my html code:

```
<a href='#' class='link'>
  <input name='status' value='delete' type='hidden'/>alert me!!
</a>
```

Comment: Your code works see http://jsfiddle.net/5Sm4s/

Comment: Your code works just fine, here is jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/L2N2Z/

Comment: fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X3kAG/1/

Comment: is there any error log in your browser console

Comment: no error it shows nothing...

Comment: I don't know why you are wrapping a hidden input inside anchor tag, looks like you should use instead data-* attribute on anchor tag. Regarding your issue, is `.link` element added dynamically to the DOM after document ready event has fired? Try to replicates your issue on jsFiddle. And what, is status equal to delete? Is the click event fired? Debug it on your side and if still not working, improve your question with all relevant informations

Answer (score 0):

No issue found in you code. I just added jQuery and this code is working and showing alert.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".link").click(function(){
        var status=$(".link input[name=status]").val();
        if( status=="delete" ) {
            alert("it works.");
        }
    });
});

</script>


<a href='#' class='link'><input name='status' value='delete' type='hidden'/>alert me!!</a>
```